# To lock on something

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I know enough about syncronization and have used it throughout some projects. But against all the odds, I still don't really understand what it means to lock **ON** something. Take C# as an example:

```
class Class1{
  private static readonly object locker = new object();
  void Method1(){
    lock(locker) { .... }
  }
}
```

Here we lock on locker object. But what if we had locked on something else:

```
//1
class Class1{
  void Method1(){
    lock("123") { .... }
  }
}

//2
class Class1{
  void Method1(){
    lock(123) { .... }
  }
}

//3
class Class1{
  void Method1(){
    lock(new object()) { .... }
  }
}

//4
class Class1{
  void Method1(){
    lock(this) { .... }
  }
}
```

what would have changed? And, again, what exactly does it mean to lock "ON" something?

P.S. I searched for the answers, there is no duplicate question!

Comment: Have you checked in msdn ? - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you lock on doesn't really matter. `lock` only cares about object identity of its argument, not about what that object means semantically.

The simple rule is: Only one locked region locking on the *same object reference* can run at the same time. Different object references used for locks do not interfere with each other.

Create a convention that ensures that code that should be mutually exclusive uses the same object reference to lock on. Doesn't matter much what object it is. An object of type `object` is fine (as long as it is the same `object` each time - so you have to store a reference to that object somewhere and pass that same reference each time).

A quiz question for you: Which of your 4 alternatives do not make sense?

Comment: I don't know which one, I have a guess but I can't explain. 1 and 2? But I don't know why.

Comment: **A new object() is fine (as long as it is the same object each time).** - how can it be the same each time? "new" creates a new object each time. To ensure that it's the same we have to save "new object()" in a variable, correct? This is the only way.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp that is correct. (This sentence was misleading, but you got it.) Regarding (3): Under what circumstances could this lock ever block? (Trying to help you understand by asking questions to *you*.)

Comment: 3) - under none circumstance, probably. However, 1) might be wrong also because two strings even with the same content can have different references.

Comment: @AlexanderSupertramp both correct. 2 also never blocks because a boxing operation results in a fresh object each time. 4 is an anti-pattern because it can lead to false blocking if some other piece of code happens to block on this class. Best practice in many cases is to create a fresh object and store it in an instance variable.

Answer (score 3):

The `lock` statement basically translates to something like this:

```
System.Threading.Monitor.Enter(x);
try { ... }
finally { System.Threading.Monitor.Exit(x); }
```

The `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` methods take an `object`(a reference type), and inside each `object` is a Win32 `CRITICAL_SECTION`, which is an internal field. That critical section is what gets locked via calls to the Win32 API.

That is why it is a really bad idea to lock on a value type as that type gets boxed and the lock is taken on the boxed value, which is different each time the boxing occurs. So by locking on a value type you effectively don't lock at all.

So locking on something, essentially means to somehow mark that something as locked and be able to check that it is locked, all in a thread safe manner. Also, only the entity that locked the object can unlock it.

Comment: that was my question: what does it mean to lock ON? What if it were C, not C#? There is no boxing in C.

Comment: It essentially means to somehow mark an object as locked and be able to check that it is locked, all in a thread safe manner.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the locked object as an item that any thread can grab if it is available.

Once a thread has grabbed it(= entered the "lock(){}" code block), the item won't be available to the others until it is released (= the thread holding it has exited the "lock(){}" code block).

If a thread B tries to get a hold of the locked object while another thread A still holds it, B will have to wait patiently until A releases it.